# How can I fix screen resolution options after an update?

Tags: updates, lubuntu, display, display-resolution

I’ve been using lubuntu 18.04 since it first came out. Time for an upgrade.

I did a fresh install of lubuntu 22.04 and had no problems. I changed my monitor to a lower resolution and it worked. I then did the full upgrade before installing other programs. My laptop restarted and was back to the maximum resolution. I can’t reduce it now. I select a lower resolution and the screen goes blank until it times out, then goes back to the max resolution.

Something in the update made it so I can’t set a lower resolution. Is there a fix to this? Maybe have to install something to make it possible?

Comment: You weren't very specific with details so there could be many causes. Lubuntu 22.04 LTS is a LTS release thus has kernel stack choice; the 22.04 & 22.04.1 media installed with the GA kernel stack that didn't change, however 22.04.2 & later media used HWE, with 22.04.3 for example recently switching from 6.2 kernel (from 23.04) to 6.5 (from 23.10) and thus maybe is the update you've encountered; but lack of specifics as to install media & that update occurred a ~week ago may mean its something different..

Comment: I'd likely (*in you case*) work out what you're using (GA or HWE kernel; or just provide details of your install media & we'll know as 22.04 had multiple ISO options!), then reboot into the kernel your system installed with (*selecting that at grub*) and see if your old behavior has returned...   If it did; you have an option of switching to GA kernel stack (*assuming you're using HWE currently*) which is supported the life of the product, and often better for older hardware!, or seeking other alternatives... again this is what I'd try (*as a first step anyway*)

Comment: I downloaded and installed the 22.04.3 LTS version earlier today. I downloaded it just a couple days ago. It worked until I did the update shortly after the installation. Now when I reboot, I can choose Ubuntu, with Linux 6.2.0-26-generic and I can change the monitor resolution, or choose the updated Ubuntu, with Linux 6.5.0-15-generic and can’t change the resolution.

Comment: This is a Q&A site (*Question and Answer site*) and not a forum, so if you have additional details, or to make clarifications, please amend your question.  Comments are for *comments* from readers to the *Original Poster* and will get removed once addressed in the question; as cleaner questions tend to get better responses (*answers being to details in your question*)

Comment: I would probably use the GA kernel stack (*as found on Lubuntu 22.04 & 22.04.1 media*), see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack for details & search for "*To downgrade from HWE/OEM to GA kernel:*" where you'll note it suggests adding that stack then testing... prior to removing the unwanted stack.. ie. you can have both installed; though some closed-source kernel modules (nvidia etc) can prevent this. You can select (at grub) which you'll use, with 5.15 (GA) & 6.5 (HWE) receiving all security fixes & thus safe options.